# Sagepay Form - Input Value

Tags: php, opayo

Im using a sagepay form, as below. The value on this form is set but i need to so that a customer can input the amount themselves.

```
   <?php
    require_once ('SagePay.php');

    $sagePay = new SagePay();
    $sagePay->setCurrency('GBP');
    $sagePay->setAmount('500');
    $sagePay->setDescription('Payment');
    $sagePay->setBillingSurname('Surname');
    $sagePay->setBillingFirstnames('First Name');
    $sagePay->setBillingCity('City');
    $sagePay->setBillingPostCode('Post Code');
    $sagePay->setBillingAddress1('Address Line One');
    $sagePay->setBillingCountry('GB');
    $sagePay->setDeliverySameAsBilling();

    $sagePay->setSuccessURL('https://www.XXXs.com/trade/success.php');
    $sagePay->setFailureURL('https://www.XXX.com/trade/fail.php');
    ?>

    <form method="POST" id="SagePayForm" action="https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/vspform-register.vsp">
        <input type="hidden" name="VPSProtocol" value= "2.23">
        <input type="hidden" name="TxType" value= "PAYMENT">
        <input type="hidden" name="Vendor" value= "wilsonscarpets">
        <input type="hidden" name="Crypt" value= "<?php echo $sagePay->getCrypt(); ?>">
            <input type="text" name="Amount" value= "">
        <input type="submit" value="continue to SagePay">
    </form>
```

This successfully goes to Sagepay with the value of 500, but im wanting to user to put in there own value within the form section, could anyone assist with this.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible, unfortunately. You must pass the required amount with a Form transaction registration within the Crypt string.

Comment: When the user enters their amount, a visit must be made back to the server to generate the `crypt`, so this will be a two-stage process.